# Best practices for large dumb data object?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am creating a java object to represent some JSON, using gson. This JSON defines the layout of a touchscreen game controller, and as such is very complex (each device has an orientation, each orientation has buttons, each button has location/size, etc.)

The program I am trying to create would serve as a standalone editor of a controller layout.

What I've done is created a class for each type (button, device, etc.) like this:

```
public class Device {
    public Button dpad;
    public Button a;
    public Button b;
    public Button start;
    public Button select;
    public Button l;
    public Button r;
    public Button menu;
    public ExtendedEdges extendedEdges;
}
```

The object itself has no logic; all serialization/deserialization is handled by gson.

I've recently read a few programming books, and one major topic was the Law of Demeter and code coupling, and this class will cause other objects to break that. However, there wouldn't really be a way to conform to good coding practices. Providing accessor methods and making fields private would simply be redundant, as the program needs write access to the entire object. Additionally, it is fairly easy to write:

```
Device device = foo(); //returns Device
bar(device.dpad.width); //Does something that involves the width of the dpad
```

Is there a better way to handle nested JSON representations, or is disobeying the Law of Demeter fine in this case?

Comment: you just said the class has no logic, which i think actually means it's ok. but you have to promise yourself never regret to have no logic inside of an object and never add logic to it.

Comment: I agree with @HuStmpHrrr, a data structure only class is just fine. What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: My problem is wouldn't this create tightly coupled code?
If the JSON structure changed, I'd have to change every reference to it.

Comment: @DanielM. it's tightly coupled but you won't need isolation either. the problem of tight coupling is it makes you difficult to make changes, especially logic. given a gamepad, assuming they don't change the design totally, like adding 5 extra buttons, you won't need to worry about the data representation anyways.

Comment: [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coupling you have to worry about here is of your data representation, which does pose risk; if this JSON object is publicly consumed, you cannot willingly *remove* elements from it, as consumers that depend on it down the road would break.  You can certainly add elements to it, as the consumers that are using the legacy structure won't necessarily care about the extra fields.

Outside of that, this sort of giant data object structure is common with serialization/deserialization of JSON data.  Again, it's coupled, but only with the actual structure of your response.